# Creating Initial ERC721 Tokens Programmatically

Tags: solidity, erc-721, constructor

I'm interested in minting 100 unique tokens in the constructor of a smart contract, but I'm having an issue where the minting function hasn't been defined yet while the constructor runs.  Do I have to deploy the smart contract first, then manually run the mint function 100 times?  Is there a programmatic way to solve this?